# How to get the model of the view outside of the view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Inside an asp.net mvc view you can access the model that is returned with the view.

If you are not in the view itself but another method that is run after the controller method completes, what [static?] method is there to get the current model of the current view being rendered?

I can access all the standard objects: session, request, response, etc.

I worked around by loading a Session variable but I don't like using session if the framework already holds it.

Comment: Where is this method and when is it being called ?

Comment: it's an event handler for SiteMap.SiteMapResolve event and it happens after the code in the view runs but before it's all returned to the browser.

Comment: Create custom ActionFilterAttribute for this, http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: @MohammadAkbari, I'll mark as answer if you answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an action filter which will be executed in the MVC request pipeline. If you want to execute some code after the action method's execution, you may override the `OnActionExecuted` method.

```
public class MyCustom : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {            
        var viewModel = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        var viewBag = filterContext.Controller.ViewBag;

        // Use any of these as needed

        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}
```

If you want this for all the requests, You can register this filter to the GlobalFilters collection inside the `RegisterRoutes` method.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new MyCustom());
```